# JaCoCo 0.8.7 has issues compiling with Android API level 32

Tags: jacoco, android-sdk-tools, android-12, android-jacoco, android-13

In my Android Studio project I used [this example](https://thsaravana.github.io/blog/jacoco-single-coverage-for-multi-module/) with its including gradle scripts to run on each of my modules and combine all results of all modules together into one single coverage report. [See GitHub playground project](https://github.com/thsaravana/jacoco-android-playground) which worked fine so far for API level 31 or lower. Since I updated the compiledSdkVersion to

```
compileSdkVersion = 32
```

the scripts are not working anymore. They run through 100% and finish successfully, but no JaCoCo results were generated!?